# Как и зачем связывать между собой nginx и Django?

Tags: django, nginx

я хочу выполнить тренировочный проект и поднять локальный сервер для сайта с несколькими страницами. Я решил использовать Django и postgres в котнтейнерах docker. Но в поисках информации нашёл статью где предлагалось также использовать nginx и gunicorn. Я не могу понять зачем нужен nginx если можно запустить сервер на Django и он сможет отдавать страницы. Я нашёл несколько статей, но так ничего и не понял, объясните пожалуйста зачем нужен nginx и gunicorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gunicorn** - [веб сервер](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_web_server) для Python.
Он обрабатывает запросы по http протоколу.

**Nginx** - тоже веб сервер, но чаще всего он используется как [реверс-прокси](https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/obratnyy-proksi), [балансировщик нагрузки](https://journal.sweb.ru/article/chto-takoe-balansirovschik-nagruzki-i-kak-on-rabotaet) или [кэш сервер](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

Для обучения - лучше отложить его интеграцию на потом, как оптимизацию существующего решения.

Comment: Спасибо большое